# How to reset variable to default values in getx?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am creating an app that has multiple questions (like a quiz) and I am using Getx for state management.

in the main method I initialize controllers as follows

```
void main() {
  Get.put(HomeScreenController());
  Get.put(QuestionsController());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

in the home screen I have a pageview and I am using HomeScreenController() to manage it.
The last page of the page view has a button to go back to the initial page. For my case, I want to reset all variables in both controllers to their initial values.

I have tried one solution, it worked but I feel like it is tedious to do for other controllers that has so many variables which is calling a method that reset the variables manually.

The other solution that I have tried is to dispose the controllers when the user clicks on the button calling Get.put(HomeScreenController()); in the build method of the home screen.

```
onPressed: () {
                    qCon.dispose();
                    controller.dispose();
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomeWrapper.id);
                  },
```

but I got an error that says

```
A HomeScreenController was used after being disposed.

'Once you have called dispose() on a HomeScreenController, it can no longer be used.
```

is there anyway to do what I am trying to do other than updating variable manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Turns out that

```
Get.reset();
```

do the job when initializing controllers in the home screen

also calling

```
Get.put(ControllerName());
```

in a build method will re-initialize the controller